# Publish more project from solution

Tags: visual-studio

Someone can help me deploy solution have 4 project. I can not find Publish all project in menu visual.
thank so much.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQFxh.png)

Comment: Did you try selecting all projects in the solution explorer? This should enable `Deploy Selection` currently disabled in your menu.